# How to make Routes work in Multiple CodeIgniter Applications?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

### Structure of CodeIgniter App

www.domain.com
- /assets
- /system

- /portal   ( application 1 )
- /members  ( application 2 )
- /admin    ( application 3 )
- /products ( application 4 )

> ```
> portal.php      ( portal application index page )
>
> members.php     ( members application index page )
>
> admin.php       ( admin application index page )
>
> products.php    ( products application index page )
> ```

URLS of INDEX ( working )

http://www.domain.com/portal.php <--------- working

http://www.domain.com/members.php <--------- working

http://www.domain.com/admin.php <--------- working

http://www.domain.com/products.php <--------- working

ROUTES

### members routes.php

```
$route['mem/display_list'] = "members/get_list";
```

### portal routes.php

```
$route['por/display_list'] = "portal/get_list";
```

### admin routes.php

```
$route['adm/display_list'] = "admin/get_list";
```

### products routes.php

```
$route['prd/display_list'] = "products/get_list";
```

URL with controller

http://www.domain.com/portal.php/portal/get_list  <----- working

http://www.domain.com/admin.php/admin/get_list  <----- working

http://www.domain.com/members.php/members/get_list  <----- working

http://www.domain.com/products.php/products/get_list  <----- working

### Question :  How Can I Make it Work with routes..

http://www.domain.com/mem/display_list  <----- NOT working

http://www.domain.com/por/display_list  <----- NOT working

http://www.domain.com/adm/display_list  <----- NOT working

http://www.domain.com/prd/display_list  <----- NOT working

Is it about configuring multiple index.php in .htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess Workaround is acceptable for your app ? or you need other way of  doing this ?

Comment: you need to take a look at [codeigniter HMVC plugin](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/165952/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter is always using the index.php (in your case: portal.php, members.php, admin.php, products.php).You will have to direct every request to the right **.php** file.

So the solution will be to add RewriteRules for each of them in the **.htaccess** file.

I have not tested it but I suppose something like this will do the work:

```
RewriteRule ^mem/(.*)$ members.php/$1 [L]
```

And of course for all the others:

```
RewriteRule ^por/(.*)$ portal.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^adm/(.*)$ admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^prd/(.*)$ products.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your working solution.. it worked really well in my apache2 vbox.. But can I ask a follow up question?

Comment: My .htaccess is working fine in my apache vbox.. but somehow when i upload / deploy it on my hosting server ( mochahost / cpanel) ... it is behaving .. abnormally.. it is loosing images and it is causing infinite loop or.. infinite redirects? Do you have any idea what can be causing it?? when it is on a cpanel.. environment???

Answer (score 0):

We also facing same issue regarding index.php so we have solution like this : 
You can use .htaccess file like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

we have index.php so you use your filename.php and skip this file name in url so your URL is working fine with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible answer I see is to have multiple `.htaccess` files. 
One on the the root and one for every individual application.
This way you can get `mod_rewrite` to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

this structure of files (multi application):

```
- application
    - admin
    - site
- system
- index.php
- admin.php
```

Your rewrite rule is wrong if you want /admin to rewrite to admin.php, with your current rule it will result in /index.php/admin.

You didn't mention if that's the problem, if it is do this:

```
RewriteRule ^/admin$ admin.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also you can debug the rewriting using **RewriteLog**: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

If that doesn't fix it please describe the current behaviour and what you expect, otherwise it's difficult to help.